# Pass v-model value

Tags: vuejs2

Is it possible to pass v-model value to another component ? I have HTML code is like below

```
<div id='example-3'>
  <input type="checkbox" id="jack" value="Jack" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="jack">Jack</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="john" value="John" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="john">John</label>
  <input type="checkbox" id="mike" value="Mike" v-model="checkedNames">
  <label for="mike">Mike</label>
</div>
```

vue.js code is like below

```
  data: {
    checkedNames: []
  }
```

I can use this v-model value in same component using below code.

```
<span>Checked names: {{ checkedNames }}</span>
```

But how can I use v-model value in another component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emit events with the v-model value each time one of the checkboxes is ticked:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mike" value="Mike" v-model="checkedNames" @change="onChange">
<label for="mike">Mike</label>

methods: {
   onChange () {
       this.$root.$emit('checkbox.changed', this.checkedNames)
    }
}
```

Listen for the event in another component:

```
// my-component.js
created () {
   this.$root.$on('checkbox-changed', payload => {
       // do something with payload...
    }
}
```

In the context of components, you should always be declaring the `data` property as a function, too.

```
data () {
    return {}
}
```

Your other option is using a state management strategy, i.e. 
[Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/), or similar.

Comment: I believe 'data must be a function' statement is only relevant when you use Vue components, not always.

Comment: You're right,  I corrected that statement. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: is it really a good idea to emit an event on the root instance? Why not the component itself? Doesn't seem right to me. The event doesn't really belong to the root.

Comment: Thanks @btl. What is the purpose of `value="Mike"` and `v-model="checkedNames"` ?

Comment: He didn't specify where the other component would be - sibling, child, parent? Root makes it more easily accessible, plus I don't think it's problematic to emit on root. So long as you're not flooding it, which I highly doubt is the case here. Personally though, I prefer Vuex 99.99% of the time.

Comment: V-model is what provides the 2 way binding mechanism on form inputs. Under the hood it's really just a wrapper for dom events like key up and on change. When you use value with v model, v model actually ignores it and treats the vue instances data as the source of truth. So it isnt necessary in this example.

Comment: Thanks @btl. So, I can leave `value` here ? Thanks.

Comment: Leave it or lose it, either way v-model will be the referenced value.

Comment: Thanks @btl. If I leave the `value`, then how can I retrieve the value of specific checkbox ?

Comment: Either by the id of the input element, `id="jack"`, or you access a value by it's index within the array.

Comment: Thanks @btl. May be you are wrong. From `id="jack"` I can extract `id` value as `jack` not the checkbox value. I think I have to mention `value="something"`. After that I can extract value.